# Grub-install: device vs partition

Tags: linux, boot, grub

Grub can be installed to a device (`grub-install /dev/sda`) and to a certain partition (`grub-install /dev/sda1`) - as I understood. My question - if we install it to a partition will grub-installer write something to MBR? If not, how bios/uefi will find out from what partition to load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install Grub to a partition, nothing is modified outside that partition. In particular, the MBR (if the disk has classical DOS partitions) is not modified. If you do that, Linux can only be booted if the bootloader in the BIOS or UEFI knows where to look for it. The reason to install Grub on a partition is when you already have another bootloader in the MBR that knows where to load it, typically another operating system that has its own boot menu. Many bootloaders from other operating systems offer to boot primary partitions that have the “active” flag set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just didn't understand "MBR (if the disk has classical DOS partitions)" - as I know MBR has and Windows and Linux and other OS. To say it correct MBR is just part of partition table types: MBR and GPT and both of them have MBR.

Comment: @iJava GPT doesn't use a MBR (it leaves the first 512 bytes free, usually what is there is a “protective MBR” so that tools that understand MBR but not GPT think that the disk has no free space). And there are partition schemes other than MBR and GPT.